# Move options between two select boxes, php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

hi guys pls help me with this i dont know how to start to send this function to the php database. pls help me i need to send the right box to the database tnx the function of the jquery is working but i cannot think of how do i insert this to the database pls help me with this:) tnx all move options(text) two the next box and insert to the php database.

```
select.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Jquery move listbox items from left to right example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



function move_list_items(sourceid, destinationid)
{
    $("#"+sourceid+"  option:selected").appendTo("#"+destinationid);
}

//this will move all selected items from source list to destination list
function move_list_items_all(sourceid, destinationid)
{
    $("#"+sourceid+" option").appendTo("#"+destinationid);
}

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
       select {
      width:200px;
      height:100px;
    }
    </style>
     </head>

     <body>
     <form action="submit.php" method="post">
     <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

     <tbody>

     <tr>

       <td colspan="2">
             <select id="from_select_list" multiple="multiple" name="from_select_list"> 
             <option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="mango">Mango</option> <option value="bannana">Bannana</option> <option value="grapes">Grapes</option> 
       </select>
    </td>

    <td colspan="2">
        <select id="to_select_list" multiple="multiple" name="to_select_list"> 
        <option value="winder">Winter</option> <option value="summer">Summer</option>     <option value="rainy">Rainy</option> <option value="Spring">Spring</option> 
        </select>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td><input id="moveright" type="button" value="Move Right"       onclick="move_list_items('from_select_list','to_select_list');" /></td>

    <td><input id="moverightall" type="button" value="Move Right All" onclick="move_list_items_all('from_select_list','to_select_list');" /></td>

    <td><input id="moveleft" type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="move_list_items('to_select_list','from_select_list');" /></td>

<td><input id="moveleftall" type="button" value="Move Left All" onclick="move_list_items_all('to_select_list','from_select_list');" /></td>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
 </tr>

 </tbody>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

connection.php
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "copy";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
?>


submit.php
<?php
include 'connection.php'
?>
```

Comment: Let me clarify your question - you want to know how to add the selected items from the right select box into a database with PHP?  If so, we need to see what you have tried in PHP.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams yah that what i need:)

Comment: @Surreal Dreams but i dont know how to start submit.php

Comment: Huge problem. (1) you need a server with a database (?MySQL) with tables of columns and rows (2) PHP on the server (3) knowledge of how to use jQuery's .ajax.

Comment: @TimSPQR yah i have some knowledge about jquery and php have also some codes for that like this i ask another question about this jquery php function:) tnx for your reply

Comment: @user3211646 when you submit the form, the form data is send to the action of the form.  In this case, it's submit.php.  if you're not seeing submit.php run, check the path to ensure the form has the correct path to submit.php.

Answer (score 0):

change the select option name into array then only u can get all the selected items

```
<td colspan="2">
    <select id="to_select_list" multiple="multiple" name="to_select_list[]"> 
    <option value="winder">Winter</option> <option value="summer">Summer</option>     <option value="rainy">Rainy</option> <option value="Spring">Spring</option> 
    </select>
</td>
```

in submit.php you can check like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```